# libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/006: Permission denied. libusb requires write access to USB device nodes

Tags: usb, permissions, udev, serial-port

I am connecting my FTDI Device with Laptop USB. I was following all the steps given in the link [How to build libftdi git under Linux](http://developer.intra2net.com/mailarchive/html/libftdi/2013/msg00014.html)

But after installing.. When I was running `./eeprom` it is throwing:

```
Unable to open device -1: (libusb_open() failed)ftdi_read_eeprom: -2 (USB device unavailable)
```

I installed FTDI D2XX driver from link:

[D2XX for Linux](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt)

After installing, I was trying some examples to write in USB EEPROM.

```
$sudo ./write
```

It is throwing:

```
libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/002/006: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes
```

I was setting

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/85-ftdi.rules
SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="660", GROUP="ftdi-user"
```

Then also, it is not working. Same error is coming.

Answer (score 2):

`SYSFS` was deprecated in favor of `ATTR`/`ATTRS`. See [hotplug/udev.git](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/hotplug/udev.git/commit/?id=6d87ee2e0024074b77001e57ff1d7b7d24b1be68)

Try with:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", MODE="660", GROUP="ftdi-user"
```